# Test python function from within editor

Tags: ide, filetype-python

I am writing python 3 code from within vim.

There is a function within my file like this:

```
def seconds_to_text(seconds):
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))
```

Is there a way for me to see what it outputs for certain input values from within vim?

How can I see what `seconds_to_text(30)` would output without leaving vim?

Answer (score 5):

Not really a "Vim answer", but writing a unit test and running the unit test(s) for the current file is probably the best way to do this.

Specifically for Python you can use [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html):

```
import datetime

def seconds_to_text(seconds):
    """Convert number of seconds to a textual representation.

    >>> seconds_to_text(42)
    '0:00:42'
    >>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=666))
    '0:11:06'
    """
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

And then just use `:!python %` to run this file.

Or if you don't want to modify the Python files, you can use:

```
:!python -m doctest %
```

Or as a more convenient mapping:

```
augroup python_test
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype python nnoremap <Leader>t :execute ':!python -m doctest %'<CR>
augroup end
```

---

If you only want to run the current function, you can use something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest, sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        doctest.testmod()
    else:
        for f in sys.argv[1:]:
            doctest.run_docstring_examples(globals()[f], globals())
```

And then use `:!python % seconds_to_text`; a useful mapping might be something like:

```
fun! TestFunction()
    " Find function under cursor
    let l:save = winsaveview()
    normal [[
    let l:fun = substitute(getline('.'), 'def \(\w*\)(.*', '\1', '')
    execute ':!python % ' . l:fun
    call winrestview(l:save)
endfun

augroup python_test
    autocmd!
    autocmd Filetype python nnoremap <Leader>t :call TestFunction()<CR>
augroup end
```

Which will run the tests for the current function. Typically you shouldn't *really* need this though, since typically unit tests are be fast enough to not notice any meaningful difference between running just one vs. running all tests for a single file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the intended solution, because you technically don't leave vim, ie you are still in the vim window, but you use a shell command to run the script.

Here is a sample python3 script I created

```
def b(a):
  return str(a)

print(b(123))
```

This creates a function that returns the string representation of the parameter.

Now I save the file using `:w` and then run the script by calling executing a terminal command `:!python3 file_name.py` and this outputs `123`. So this is a way you can call a Python function. Sure, you can replace the `b(a)` function with your own function `seconds_to_text(seconds)` and do the same process.

Comment: Using a shell command is fine ;) However, I already know this isn't the best possible solution, because I don't _have_ to save the file to be able to pass a section of it to python, I can select some lines and run: `:'<,'>!python`

Comment: @theonlygusti `:w` and then `!python3` is shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command that *should* work (but it's not pretty):

```
command! -nargs=1 Pt echomsg system("python -c 'from " . expand("%:r") . " import *;print ". <f-args> . "'")
```

Decomposing:

```
command! -nargs=1 Pt            " Define a command named Pt that takes 1 argument.
echomsg system("                " The command echo the result of a system call.
python -c '                     " Execute a python string as the whole program.
from " . expand("%:r")          " Build a `from X import *` statement where X ..
. " import *;                   " .. is the current filename without extension
print ". <f-args>               " Print the command argument (see below)
. "'")                          " Close everything
```

You can use the command like so:

```
# test.py
def test(a):
   return a*2
```

And run:

```
:Pt test(21)
42
```

See:

- `:h command`
- `:h nargs`
- `:h echomsg`
- `:h system`
- `:h expand`
- `:h f-args`